# How to set 'Allow text to overflow shape' true for Chart Data Labels in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, charts, label

I've created a macro to duplicate a Chart to a new Workbook, thereby unlinking the Pivot Table data source. It then sets the new Data Source, and applies some formatting to the Data Labels, so the new Chart has the same look-and-feel as the old one.

This is the section of code that sets the Data Label's format:

```
' Select the Data Labels
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select

' Apply fancy formatting to the Data Labels
With Selection
    .ShowCategoryName = True
    .ShowValue = True
    .ShowLegendKey = -1
    .Separator = " - "
    .Position = xlLabelPositionBestFit

    With .Font
        .Bold = False
        .Color = RGB(89, 89, 89)
    End With

    With .Format
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .TextFrame2.WordWrap = msoFalse
        '.TextFrame.HorizontalOverflow = xlOartHorizontalOverflowOverflow
        .AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle

        With .Line
            .Visible = True
            .Weight = 0.75
            .DashStyle = msoLineSolid
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(191, 191, 191)
        End With
    End With
End With
```

However, when I uncomment the line that sets the Horizontal Overflow, I get this error:

> Run-time error '438':
>
> Object does not support this property or method

How can I set the overflow propery shown circled in red, below, to `true`?

As you can see, it successfully changed the `Wrap text in shape` to `false` (at the bottom):

[image]

I get that it's not difficult for me to go and tick the box when it's finished running my code, but it's part of a larger script that generates ~100 charts.  I'd really like to get it to run from start to finish without my intervention, after it generates each chart.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that property is exposed in VBA: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/datalabel-object-excel